# Looking through entire collection for string

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm making an authentication system for my C# program, I want the program to:

- Connect to MongoDB server (done)
- Go to right database & collection (done)
- Look through all objects in collection and find if there's a `key` with a specific string value

Example of my objects in the collection:

```
_id: "XXX"
hwid: "the key/value pair that I want to filter for"
details: {
    discord_id: int
    discord_name: "string"
    ip_address: "string"
    serial: "XXX (same as _id name)"
}
```

So what I want to achieve is is that my program checks if my string (`HardwareID.Output()`) is in any of the collection's `hwid` keys.

The code I have so far:

```
public static void Connect()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("connection works");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("monza");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<dynamic>("whitelist");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("hwid", HardwareID.Output()); // grabs string from another class
        var dataObjects = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
    }
```

However I get the this error when trying this:

```
CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<dynamic, bool>>'
```

Regardless of the error I don't think this is all I need to achieve my goal and I can't find any information on how to do this iN C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why you're using dynamic. Try this:

```
public static void Connect()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("monza");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("whitelist");

            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("hwid", HardwareID.Output()); // grabs string from another class
            var dataObjects = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
        }
```